# Seeing a distribution is integrable

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to do the following exercise :

> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be $1-$forms on a compact manifold $M^n$ such that $(\alpha\wedge \beta)_p \neq 0, \forall p\in M$ and such that $\alpha\wedge \beta$ is closed. Then the distribution generated by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is integrable.

Well I think the idea would be use to use the frobenius theorem and try and show that we have a differential ideal. We know that $d(\alpha \wedge \beta)=0=d\alpha\wedge \beta-\alpha\wedge d\beta$ and so $d\alpha\wedge \beta=\alpha\wedge d\beta$. I have no clue where we can use the fact that $(\alpha\wedge \beta)_p \neq 0$ is relevant to check that $d\alpha =\alpha \wedge \eta$ or $\beta\wedge \eta$ for some $\eta$ and analogously for $d\beta$.

Any step towards the right direction is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement that $\alpha\wedge\beta$ be nonvanishing is there to ensure that the kernel $\mathcal{D}=\{v\in TM:\alpha(v)=\beta(v)=0\}$ is indeed a distribution; otherwise it may have nonconstant rank.

Let $I$ be the ideal generated by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (or equivalently the set of forms which vanish on $\mathcal{D}$). Another characterization more useful to this problem is that $\omega\in I$ iff $\alpha\wedge\beta\wedge\omega=0$. Can you show this?

(Hint: Consider a local coframe containing $\alpha$ and $\beta$.)

Comment: Yeah I think I can show that , and then it's easy to see that it's a differential ideal since we have that the wedge of a $1$-form with itself is zero.